# PSET4 CS50 Reflect Assignment; Code is failing the tests

Tags: c, swap, cs50

I can't find a way to fix these two errors despite my pic turns out fine. Would appreciate it if anyone can enlighten me.

This is the report I get:

> ***:( reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
>
>       expected "0 0 255\n255 0...", not "255 0 0\n0 0 2..."*** 
>   :) reflect correctly filters 1x3 image 
>   :) reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image
>   :) reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
>   ***:( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image
>
>       expected "100 110 120\n7...", not "100 110 120\n4..."***

And this is my code:

```
RGBTRIPLE tmp[width];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= width / 2; j++)
    {
        tmp[j] = image[i][j];
        image[i][j] = image[i][width - 1 - j];
        image[i][width - 1 - j] = tmp[j];
    }
}
return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution;**

Condition in the for loop needs a small tweak;

```
j < width / 2
```

**Understanding why;**

For 1x2 image, you have 2 pixels in one row. Width is 2. Just 1 iteration is enough for this. In the old scenario, 1st iteration is executed when j=0. But then 2nd iteration is also executed because j=1 is still within the condition (equals to width/2). 2nd iteration is unnecessary. You are just reflecting twice which results in no change in the image.

For 4x4 image, the similar issue. You should finish reflection with 2 iterations when j = 0, and when j = 1. However, when j = 2 (j is still equal and smaller than width/2), 3rd iteration is executed and replaces 3rd pixel with 1st pixel which is wrong. Because you had already replaced them once.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here is what caused it.

I assume the code you are showing is only for the left side of the image (i.e. copy the left side of image into a temp image and copy right side of image into left side). This part is correct except for the '<=' vs '<' issue earik87 pointed out.

You did not show your code for the right side of image, which copies the left side of temp image into the right side. I used a similar for loop and assume you did the same. I set the initial value of j to be width / 2, and here is the issue:

**By using width / 2, you are dividing an int by an int, and the result will always be an int.**

For example, if width=5, width/2 will return 2, means the right side of image starts with column 2. But the column 2 is the middle line of the image. What I really tried to do is starting with column 3. So I used

```
width / 2 + 1
```

But this gives me another issue, when width is even, say width = 4, I will be starting with column 3, while I should start with column 2.

To make this work regardless of even or odd, we can use round() and a floating denominator:

```
round(width / 2.0)
```

width / 2.0 will return a float, and round() will round this float to the nearest integer.