# PSET4: Filter(less)

Tags: arrays, c, debugging, cs50, edx

I am attempting the Filter problem of Pset4(less comfortable). I wrote this code below to reflect the image. But it doesn't work at all. It compiles alright however.

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)  //for rows
    {
        int start = 0;
        for (int end = width; end > 0; end--)
        {
            BYTE tempR, tempB, tempG;
            if(start < end)
            {
                tempR = image[i][start].rgbtRed;
                tempB = image[i][start].rgbtBlue;
                tempG = image[i][start].rgbtGreen;
                image[i][start].rgbtRed = image[i][end].rgbtRed;
                image[i][start].rgbtBlue = image[i][end].rgbtBlue;
                image[i][start].rgbtGreen = image[i][end].rgbtGreen;
                image[i][end].rgbtRed = tempR;
                image[i][end].rgbtBlue = tempB;
                image[i][end].rgbtGreen = tempG;
                start += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I saw the comment, this looked like a "reverse the order of all pixels on a [raster] line", based on the code.

A few issues ...

`end` should start at `width - 1` [and *not* `width`]. It's starting at one *past* the last pixel in the row (i.e. the first pixel of the *next* row). For the last row, this is UB [undefined behavior].

So, the effect was a shift by one pixel and I bet the first and last pixels of the row looked "interesting" ...

The inner loop condition should be `start < end` instead of `end > 0` and we should eliminate the `if (start < end)` altogether.

In addition to correctness, this will eliminate the last 50% of the inner loops. Those were *not* transferring data [because the `if` would become false and remain so for the rest of the row]. So, the loop was doing twice as many loop iterations (i.e.) only the first iterations did useful work.

In other words, the inner `for` loop was doing `width` iterations instead of `width / 2` iterations.

---

Here's the cleaned up and corrected code:

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void
reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    // for rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        int start = 0;

        for (int end = width - 1;  start < end;  --end, ++start) {
            BYTE tempR, tempB, tempG;

            tempR = image[i][start].rgbtRed;
            tempB = image[i][start].rgbtBlue;
            tempG = image[i][start].rgbtGreen;

            image[i][start].rgbtRed = image[i][end].rgbtRed;
            image[i][start].rgbtBlue = image[i][end].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][start].rgbtGreen = image[i][end].rgbtGreen;

            image[i][end].rgbtRed = tempR;
            image[i][end].rgbtBlue = tempB;
            image[i][end].rgbtGreen = tempG;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Although, the optimizer *may* generate efficient code from the above, here's a version where `start` and `end` are pointers. This makes it easier for the compiler to see the intent, and is simpler and easier to read:

```
// Reflect image horizontally
void
reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    // for rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        RGBTRIPLE *start = &image[i][0];
        RGBTRIPLE *end = &image[i][width - 1];

        for (;  start < end;  --end, ++start) {
            BYTE tempR, tempB, tempG;

            tempR = start->rgbtRed;
            tempB = start->rgbtBlue;
            tempG = start->rgbtGreen;

            start->rgbtRed = end->rgbtRed;
            start->rgbtBlue = end->rgbtBlue;
            start->rgbtGreen = end->rgbtGreen;

            end->rgbtRed = tempR;
            end->rgbtBlue = tempB;
            end->rgbtGreen = tempG;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What a beautiful answer! Thanks!

Comment: What about this code in here? It is much shorter than yours.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747714/pset4-cs50-reflect-assignment-code-is-failing-the-tests/61754358#61754358