# reflect for cs50. Trying to reflect an image, but only the first row pixels is swaped

Tags: c, cs50

So, my task is to reflect image pixel by pixel to make a mirror image. Here is my original code for the function

```
    void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
int tempr, tempg, tempb;
for (int i = 0; i<height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j<width; j++)
    {
        tempr= image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        tempg= image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
        tempb = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        image[i][j].rgbtRed=image[i][width-1].rgbtRed;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen=image[i][width-1].rgbtGreen;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue=image[i][width-1].rgbtBlue;
        image[i][width-1].rgbtRed=tempr;
        image[i][width-1].rgbtGreen=tempg;
        image[i][width-1].rgbtBlue=tempb;
        width--;
    }
}

return;
}
```

The problem is that code seems to work fine but just in the first row. For some reason the loop for i doesn't work. In another discussion i saw the advice not to divide pixels for rgb but just swap them. It did't work out, cause the compiler says that I cannot assign struct to int. Tried to add another i++ somewhere in the code, just to make it work in any way, but still, only mistakes. I rewrote it one more time just to be sure, but the result is the same. Can you help me and tell, what i dont see here?

Someone asked to write the caller function. It wasn't written by me, but still, here it is
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

```
// Define allowable filters
char *filters = "bgrs";

// Get filter flag and check validity
char filter = getopt(argc, argv, filters);
if (filter == '?')
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid filter.\n");
    return 1;
}

// Ensure only one filter
if (getopt(argc, argv, filters) != -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Only one filter allowed.\n");
    return 2;
}

// Ensure proper usage
if (argc != optind + 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: filter [flag] infile outfile\n");
    return 3;
}

// Remember filenames
char *infile = argv[optind];
char *outfile = argv[optind + 1];

// Open input file
FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    return 4;
}

// Open output file
FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
if (outptr == NULL)
{
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
    return 5;
}

// Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

// Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

// Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
    bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
{
    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
    return 6;
}

int height = abs(bi.biHeight);
int width = bi.biWidth;

// Allocate memory for image
RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
if (image == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory to store image.\n");
    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    return 7;
}

// Determine padding for scanlines
int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

// Iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    // Read row into pixel array
    fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);

    // Skip over padding
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
}

// Filter image
switch (filter)
{
    // Blur
    case 'b':
        blur(height, width, image);
        break;

    // Grayscale
    case 'g':
        grayscale(height, width, image);
        break;

    // Reflection
    case 'r':
        reflect(height, width, image);
        break;

    // Sepia
    case 's':
        sepia(height, width, image);
        break;
}

// Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

// Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

// Write new pixels to outfile
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    // Write row to outfile
    fwrite(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, outptr);

    // Write padding at end of row
    for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
    {
        fputc(0x00, outptr);
    }
}

// Free memory for image
free(image);

// Close infile
fclose(inptr);

// Close outfile
fclose(outptr);

return 0;
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and single step through it to find where the execution goes haywire.  If you can't run it under a debugger sprinkle print statements throughout the code to help you debug what's going wrong.

Comment: I've done it before asking. And done it one more time now. Everything is fine, i==1, there goes the second loop, and... debugger closed. 2 times. So it didn't help

Comment: It is probably helpful to also include the caller function. There is probably something wrong there. Btw: use uint and not int. height and width should be always positive.

Comment: And even the tool from cs50 to check the solutions says that with the images like 1*3 or 1*4, i mean one row, the code works fine, but not with 2*3, 2*4

Comment: The fact that the debugger closed is probably pretty relevant here.  Typically debuggers (being system tools that must work reliably) don't just close when running a program.   Could you elaborate more on what see when running under the debugger including any error messages?

Comment: Ok, i'll try to describe more detailed. Debugger closed when i try to click "next step" too quickly. With no mistakes, at all. That what i thought. So i tried to set a stop point right near return. Well.. debugger crashed and wrote that some code was changed on disk, and whether i want to save it. It shows it:
"@name": null,
            "@pid": null,
            "@proxy": null,
            "@runner": null
to:
"@name": "output",
            "@pid": 6813,
            "@proxy": 6894,
            "@runner": "GDBMonitor"

Comment: "The project settings file (.c9/project.settings ) was updated outside the IDE. If you did not make the changes we suggest reviewing the file before accepting. Do you want to accept the new settings?"

and that's the only mistake which i managed to get from debugger

Comment: You're going to have a tough time debugging programs if you can't get the debugger to work.  I realize it's not the answer to your question or the one that you want but if you could reliable step through this program in the debugger I think you'd see what' wrong pretty quickly.  Like I said before, if you can't use the debugger, printf is your friend.  Hint: Put a printf as the first statement inside of both for loops and print the values of the loop counters and the values of the variables used in the comparison to see if the loop should continue executing.

Comment: Okay, now i understood what did you meen it your first comment (sorry, the second week of programing here). So... there is clearly a problem. During the first loop j goes through all the number to 299 (like i need). The second one - up to 149. Then 70+-. And in the end it just disappears and there is only printf for i. So.. i guess i messed up with width-1 statement and i have to make another variable=width and redeclare it every loop. I'm gonna try it

Comment: @JJF yes, it worked. Thank you. I am not quite sure what kind of mistake I made, but at least i found it. Thank you. I got to remember this method. Still cannot understand why debbuger was crashing with no mistakes

Comment: You gotta be a debugger if you're going to be a programmer. Good for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PSET4 CS50 Reflect Assignment; Code is failing the tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747714/pset4-cs50-reflect-assignment-code-is-failing-the-tests)